# Juniper ScreenOS Windows 7 Vpn client

Tags: vpn, firewall, remote-access, juniper, screenos

I'd like to configure my Juniper firewall so users can VPN from the windows built in client. Can anyone provide me with that information on how to go about configuring this? (I'm somewhat new to juniper firewalls)

Answer (score 1):

First response on google:

http://kb.juniper.net/kb/documents/public/VPN/ScreenOS_Windows_L2TP_IPSec.pdf